# StoryBoard always starts with original co-ordinates after Transform in xaml (windows store app)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a canvas that has a double animation implemented after it is transformed closer to a specific co-ordinates.

The transform and double animation works fine. But after the animation is complete, the canvas resets into right most corner of the layout. Weird thing is, this behavior does not exist if I do not give any width to the canvas or remove the grid columns.

Any ideas what am I missing here? I am trying to have source on the right of the page and target on the left.

EDIT -1:
After some testing I realized that the values are not resetting, but the storyboard/double animation itself is moving the canvas far right. I do not understand what is causing this though.

EDIT-2:
On further investigation, looks like double animation always starts with initial co-ordinates of the canvas rather than using the current location. Even when from co-ordinates are mentioned relative to whole grid, it only animates based on original layout. Is there a way Force the storyboard to use current location?

Here is the code:
XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Canvas Name="target"  >
        <Rectangle  Width="150" Height="150" Fill="Gray"  />
    </Canvas>
<Canvas Name="source"  ManipulationMode="All" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle Name="testRectangle"  Width="150" Height="150" Fill="Blue"   />
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
Public Point p = new Point(225, 225);
 public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            DragabbleRectangle();
        }

private void DragabbleRectangle()
        {
            source.ManipulationDelta += source_ManipulationDelta;
            source.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform(); ;
        }

void source_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
Canvas rect = sender as Canvas;
Point pT= rect.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content).TransformPoint(origin);
CompositeTransform tT = rect.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
tT.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
tT.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

var distance = Math.Pow(pT.X - p.X,2) + Math.Pow(pT.Y-p.Y, 2);
if (distance  < 2500)
            {
                Duration d = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                rect.Margin = new Thickness(0);
                rect.RenderTransform = tT;// new CompositeTransform();
                DoubleAnimation xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { To = p.X, From = pT.X,
                Duration = d, EasingFunction = new QuinticEase() };
                DoubleAnimation yAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { To = p.Y, From = pT.Y,
                Duration = d, EasingFunction = new QuinticEase() };
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)");
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
                Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
                Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, rect);
                storyboard.Children.Add(xAnimation);
                storyboard.Children.Add(yAnimation);
                storyboard.Begin();
}
        }
```

Comment: you have found the root cause of the problem. the solution is registering a callback for storyboard's Completed event, which puts `rect` at the new location. So the next storyboard will begin from the new location.

Comment: And You need to stop and remove the storyboard after it has completed so it can not affecting a property. [How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not subscribing to the story board completed event. If this is the case you will  have to give the relative distance from the original coordinates. Here is something you can try that should do the trick:

name the root grid as layout

```
<Grid x:name="layout" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
...
...
</Grid>
```

in the code behind change the animations to relative distance...

```
Point relative = layout.TransformToVisual(source).TransformPoint(origin);
DoubleAnimation xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { To = p.X + relative.X, From = tT.TranslateX,
                Duration = d, EasingFunction = new QuinticEase() };
DoubleAnimation yAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { To = p.Y + relative.Y, From = tT.TranslateY,
                Duration = d, EasingFunction = new QuinticEase() };
```